# channel ‘mychannel’ not found in orderer when restart kafka, zookeeper and orderer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am testing the Kafka mode in Fabric Network, after I create a channel 
 named 'mychannel', I joined two ORG in it. After these actions, I tried to use 'down' and 'up' command to refresh the kafka、zookeeper and the orderer's containers.**In this way, I want to test if a peer can persistent 'channels' in different fabric network.**
When tailing the logs of Orderer, I found the problem :

```
[common.deliver] deliverBlocks -> DEBU dc9 Rejecting deliver for 192.168.11.61:60156 because channel mychannel not found
```

and I used the kafka shell tool to check topic list, and find the 'mychannel' topic disappeared.

After doing above, I create a new channel 'mychannel' which used the same 'channel.tx' . And I found the error in log:

```
UTC [common.deliver] deliverBlocks -> ERRO b1b [channel: mychannel] Error reading from channel, cause was: NOT_FOUND
```

I used command:

```
peer channel getinfo -c mychannel
```

in one org's peer , and get info, the block height is 16:

```
Blockchain info: {"height":16,"currentBlockHash":"gHOfUnVRT0pGMRssz8fUXWH4jdH/1hcPUPLBqau7L9c=","previousBlockHash":"yvKUrJDg3+60Sbc0HHKs+N5vVkW2WBJWhy9TLFGmMug="}
```

I guess the orderer genesis block's height is 0, and can't match the current block height.

How can I fix this problem? Can I use channel update method to update the channel config?

kafka mode: 4 kafka brokers, 3 zookeepers
1 orderer
2 orgs

restart orderer and kafka cluster(cmd: 'docker-compose down & up')

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you were not using externally mounted volumes with your Kafka, Zookeeper and Orderer containers.  When you run `docker-compose down` it actually destroys the containers.  If you want to start/stop the containers, you need to use `docker-compose stop` and `docker-compose start`.

If you want to preserve data in the event that the containers are destroyed (or even to upgrade them), then you need to attach external volumes to your containers.

Comment: It's right.But I am testing if peers can use the channel created when changing their orderer and kafkas. So I use 'down' but not 'stop' to simulate a diffenrent fabric network which contains orderer and use kafka mode

Comment: that's now how it works ... you would have to perform a channel update to change the orderer endpoints.  A peer can keep the ledger if the orderer disappears, but you cannot recreate the orderer from peer ledgers

Comment: Thanks, I tested to set up another orderer which contains the same peers, and the orderer getted the ledger of channel which name is 'mychannel'.